# GPU system load monitor for xfce panel

Tags: xfce, gpu, system-monitor, xfce-panel

I am trying to get a GPU system load monitor to work in xfce4 panel. Is there any way to configure the current CPU system load monitor to reflect GPU usage? I know we can run a script in genmon generic monitor but I don't have the skills necessary to create the script.

I have an AMD GPU and currently use gpu-mon --gui for monitoring but would like to have something similar to the CPU monitor in the panel, preferably for GPU load and vram mem load.

Thanks

Comment: I made a gpu `genmon` script that might be useful to start: https://github.com/marcosins/panel-monitoring-scripts/blob/main/genmon/gpu_nvidia.sh

Comment: Is there a way for this script to be modified to use Radeon drivers as opposed to nvidia?

Comment: also I would like it to read GPU usage similar to the CPU usage monitor instead of temurature